# Can an executable check whether it is running natively in .net 8.0?

Tags: native-aot

I have an asp.net 8.0 API with an endpoint that returns information about itself. I want to include the information about whether it is running natively (so AOT compiled or not).

Just looking if there is a way to get the info conclusively (without hacking).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the code is running in AOT in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635700/how-to-check-the-code-is-running-in-aot-in-c)